# Selenium Python the rows of the table from a column is not being stored in my list variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page with a table of some columns and rows.  I am trying to store the data from column 1 for each row into a list variable.  When i walk through my code there is nothing being stored in the list variable.
My loop to iterate through the table is fine as I can print out the value from column 1 for each row.
I have declared the List variable at class level.

My code snippet is:

```
def get_table_column_1_values_into_a_list(self):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body')))
        table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body')))
        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        for row in rows:
            # Get the columns
            col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]  # This is the Configuration Name column
            col_type = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[3]  # This is the Type column
            col_rows = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[4]  # This is the Rows column
            print "col_name.text = "
            print col_name.text
            print col_type.text
            print col_rows.text
            # store the value of col 1 into a  list
            DataPreviewsViewPage.col1_list_before_sort[row] = col_name.text
            print DataPreviewsViewPage.col1_list_before_sort[row]
            #    return True
        return DataPreviewsViewPage.col1_list_before_sort
        #return False
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print e
        return False
```

My List variable declaration is:

```
class DataPreviewsPage(BasePage):

    col1_list_before_sort = []
```

In the For loop how do i store the value from `col_name = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1]` into a list of items?

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: Not sure how your code is running. Isn't `row` a webElement and `DataPreviewsViewPage.col1_list_before_sort[row]` couldn't be working, if its a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just return the list of column names from the method:

```
def get_table_column_1_values_into_a_list(self):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body')))
        table_id = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'data_configuration_data_previews_ct_fields_body')))

        rows = table_id.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
        return [row.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[1].text for row in rows]
    except NoSuchElementException, e:
        print e
        return False
```

Comment: Can i store the list of column names into a list, an array?  I would like to then sort the list alphabetically.  I would like to use the sort function of the list data type.  E.g. col1_values_list.sort()

Comment: @RiazLadhani the method I've posted is already returning a list.

Comment: Yes it has returned a list.  I walked through the code with the PyCharm debug.  It has the names from col1 for each row.  Thanks very much for you help.